# how to delete rows from HBASE table by reading row keys from a text file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

In one of my projects, I have a requirement to housekeep a HBASE table by deleting the rows for the customers who are no longer associated with the bank.

I am getting a text file containing the customerid (also the row key in the HBASE table). Each line in the text file contains the unique customer id which is to be used to delete the customer details from the table.

I don't think I can use TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob to initiate a map-only job as the mapclass will expect the input to be from the table itself not a text file on HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NLineInputFormat` and `TableOutputFormat` for writing your map reduce job.

With `Tableoutputformat` you can do a `context.write(key, new Delete(key.toString().getBytes()))` inside your mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Map reduce can be used both as input(source) and output(sink) with Hbase. In your case, you need to write your own map reduce to read the data from input, and then use the reducer provided by API

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob("targetTable",null,job);
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

second parameter is null, because you are using the reducer provided by API. You just have to take care of row key and delete as mapper output, and reducer picks it up and performs he job. You can find the basic usage [here](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/mapreduce.example.html). Not your exact solution, but the concept behind the mapreduce and hbase usage